# Login to site.com, request "New Tor circuit for this site", site.com still recognizes original login

Tags: circuit, google, login, persistent, cookies

Using TorBrowser, login with *username* and *password* on site.com (e.g., google, amazon, etc.), then ask TorBrowser for "New Tor circuit for this site." **Why does site.com (sometimes) recognize this "new Tor circuit" as associated with the same *username* rather than a new, currently anonymous connection?**

- I assume "New Tor circuit" request specifically forces new Tor exit node (new IP address).
- The url is generic (not site.com/username-abc123.html).
- JavaScript disabled.
- It seems that TorBrowser has allowed site.com to put cookie or other identifying feature on this browser session that persists across "New Tor circuit" request.

**Is this expected behavior for "New Tor circuit for this site"?**

Answer (score 2):

Requesting a new circuit will get you exactly that -- a new circuit. It does not mean that Tor won't pick the same exit again, and it will not clean any cookies. It is trivial then of course for a site to recognize you again.

What you want and what was already suggested is "New Identity". Unfortunately, Tor Browser currently has to restart to get you a clean new profile. You cannot safely get a new session without restarting the browser.

A good document that goes into more detail is https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser/design/ .

This question was also previously discussed in [Tor Browser Bundle (TBB) new circuit versus new identity](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/8673/tor-browser-bundle-tbb-new-circuit-versus-new-identity) .

Answer (score 0):

It could be a session cookie. 
Try using a new identity, instead of *merely* a new circuit. I believe that the latter will get rid of any session cookies.

Comment: session cookies can be not the only reason

Answer (score 0):

It's a persistent cookies + browser fingerprinting. You need to use a *separated/dedicated* virtual machine for web browsing to be 100% sure to "split identities"